# Is it possible to pass specific parameters to gmdate() year, month, day, hour, minute

Tags: php

The way I am obtaining the data for a date is having specifically the year, month, day, hour and minute and I would like to get the current GMT value of each. The hour comes back in 24 hour time. For instance

```
$_POST['calendar_month'];
$_POST['calendar_day'];
$_POST['calendar_year'];
$_POST['calendar_starttime_hour'];
$_POST['calendar_starttime_minute'];
$_POST['calendar_endtime_hour'];
$_POST['calendar_endtime_minute'];
```

I need to get the `gmdate()` of each of these, but I cant seem to return the correct values or if it is even possible.

I tried `gmdate("2017")` just to see what returns and for some reason, `1970` comes back. I also tried

```
gmdate("m",strtotime($_POST['calendar_year']));
gmdate("H",strtotime(date("H",$_POST['calendar_starttime_year'])));
```

But these also do not work as well.

Is it possible to pass specific params to `gmdate()`? And if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the values from your `$_POST` array properly to the `gmtdate` function. A proper date is always constructed of:

`hour, minute, second, day, month, year`.

Example:

```
echo gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", mktime($_POST['calendar_starttime_hour'], 
$_POST['calendar_starttime_minute'], 0, $_POST['calendar_day'], 
$_POST['calendar_month'], $_POST['calendar_year']));
```

Comment: So I took your code example and I am passing to the script `05 31 2017 13:00:00` and what's returned back to me `Jul 05 2019 13:00:00` Can you make any sense of this?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, but your day and month are backwards so I edited it for you.

Comment: @CesarBielich thanks. Yes, the day and month were in the wrong order. Glad I could help!